# How does Windows Vista/7/2008 bootmgr work behind the scene?

Tags: windows, bootmgr, bcdedit

It always used to be possible to transfer a Windows installation (NT/2000/XP/2003) to a new boot medium by:

- Recreating the partition table and MBR
- Copying the partitions using ntfsclone
- Tricky part: The disk geometry had to remain the same and the partition where ntldr resided had to start at the same LBA sector as before

Is this still possible with Windows (Vista/7/2008)? Would such a procedure work?

- Copy partition table, with disk signature (!) and MBR
- Possibly resize partitions to fit the harddrive
- Ntfsclone "System Reserved Partition" and "Boot Parition".
- Do one or both still have to start at the same sector on old and new hard disk?

Can you explain how bootmgr and bcd really work under the hood, as opposed to e.g. grub or ntldr? Is there a first and second stage? Does it keep block lists somewhere?

Update: My original problem turned out to be hardware related. Question rephrased to address the broader issue.

Comment: Actually I did. Found nothing as to why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

bootmgr is not aware of "drive letters", that's something Windows does late in the boot process (and is configured in the registry, absolutely nothing to do with the physical disk configuration).

Using Linux to clone a system is not supported by Microsoft. In short, the official answer is *Don't Do That*. You should use Windows PE. DISM can create and apply WIM image files, which is Microsoft's preferred format (the same one used by Windows Setup).

Cloning a machine generally follows:

1. Setup reference machine. Run `sysprep`.
2. Boot WinPE. Use `dism` to capture the drive. Something like this batch file:

   ```
   @ECHO OFF
   IF %1 == "" GOTO DIE:
   CHKDSK /X C:
   CHKDSK /X D:
   IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 0 GOTO DIE:
   DISM /Capture-Image /ImageFile:Z:\Path\To\Images\%1.wim /Name:Boot   /CaptureDir:C:\ /Compress:fast
   DISM /Append-Image  /ImageFile:Z:\Path\To\Images\%1.wim /Name:Windows /CaptureDir:D:\
   :DIE
   ```

   This may need to be modified if you have a non-standard partition layout.
3. Boot the destination computer to WinPE. Use `diskpart` and `dism` to apply the image:

   Standard `diskpart` script to configure partitions:

   ```
   SEL DISK 0
   CLEAN
   CREATE PART PRI SIZE=350
   ACT
   FORMAT QUICK
   ASSIGN LETTER=M
   CREATE PART PRI
   FORMAT QUICK
   ASSIGN LETTER=O
   EXIT
   ```

   Standard `dism` batch file to write image:

   ```
   @ECHO OFF
   IF %1 == "" GOTO DIE:
   DISKPART /s Diskpart-Standard.script
   IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 0 GOTO DIE:
   DISM /Apply-Image /ImageFile:%1 /Index:1 /ApplyDir:M:\
   DISM /Apply-Image /ImageFile:%1 /Index:2 /ApplyDir:O:\
   IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 0 GOTO DIE:
   BCDEDIT -STORE M:\BOOT\BCD -set {bootmgr} device partition=M:
   BCDEDIT -STORE M:\BOOT\BCD -set {memdiag} device partition=M:
   BCDEDIT -STORE M:\BOOT\BCD -set {default} device partition=O:
   BCDEDIT -STORE M:\BOOT\BCD -set {default} osdevice partition=O:
   :DIE
   ECHO Script ended...
   ```

Your process might work, but you likely are missing those last four `bcdedit` lines from the script.

Note this does not configure WinRE, but you shouldn't need it if you have WinPE around anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response. Some day I might even invest the time to learn the native Microsoft tools. You didn't include any details on bootmgr's inner workings, though.

Comment: Sorry, this answer is rather off topic for [SU]. On [SF] we consider "don't do that" type answers to be *The Right Answer* sometimes. I'll leave this here for reference but you're right that it doesn't suit the question here.